# PHPMYADMIN | How could we sync two tables in two different MySQL databases (Within same server)?

Tags: mysql, laravel

- I have two MySQL databases `site1` & `site2`[Both reside in the same
  server].
- I have a table named `users` in `both` the above databases(Exact
  same structure in both `site1` & `site2`). The structure is as shown
  below :

  [image]

**How it works :**

So `site1` & `site2` would have users registering themselves to the database(for some use-cases) via a mobile application. So a user download the mobile app -> depending on the user location, they're going to fall into either `site1` or `site2` -> User register themselves & this is how `new row entries` get generated in the `users` table.

**What am i trying to achieve ?**

Since the same user may come to both sites occasionally, `site1` or `site2` should have the `users` table synchronized for all columns. So **based on unique phone numbers**(`phone`), the rows of `users` table in both `site1` & `site2` should always be synchronized. How can we achieve this ?? I know that triggers is an option, but I'd appreciate a sample code for the format to be used..or any hints would be much appreciated. Now sure how helpful an `event` is for this use-case. Can someone please assist ?

PHP framework used is Laravel.

Comment: Isn't using a single database a solution for you instead?

Comment: No @ZoliSzabó : Because, this is kind of selling app & there's a table call products which would be different for different locations.. Do you know how to get this tables synced ?

Comment: You can use Phinx migrations or the SQLyog Ultimate Schema Synchronization Tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is to use [MySQL triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html).

Here is a brief tutorial on how to use triggers to insert new values to a second table: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql-trigger-to-insert-row-into-another-table

**EDIT:** Included below the full tutorial from the above link, in case it will disappear from the original source.

Let us first create a table. The CREATE command is used to create a table.

```
mysql> create table Table1
   -> (
   -> id int,
   -> name varchar(100)
   -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.62 sec)
```

Let us now create another table.

```
mysql> create table Table2
   -> (
   -> id int,
   -> name varchar(100)
   -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.49 sec)
```

Now, the following is how you can create a trigger.

```
mysql> delimiter #
mysql> create trigger Table1Trigger after insert on Table1
   -> for each row
   -> begin
   ->  insert into Table2(id, name) values (new.id, new.name);
   -> end#
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;
```

To create a trigger, we need to change the delimiter.

Inserting the row into Table1 activates the trigger and inserts the records into Table2. To insert record in Table1.

```
mysql> insert into Table1 values(1,'John'),(2,'Smith'),(3,'Carol');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.28 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

To check if the records are inserted in both tables or not.

```
mysql> select *from Table1;
```

Here is the output that shows record inserted successfully in Table1.

```
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | John  |
|    2 | Smith |
|    3 | Carol |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To check for second table.

```
mysql>  select *from Table2;
```

The following is the output that shows record inserted successfully in Table2.

```
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|    1 | John  |
|    2 | Smith |
|    3 | Carol |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you... but in my case the trigger should insert the content of table1 to a table in another database within the same server.,.. How can we achieve that ??

Comment: Within one db server, you can reference different databases with dots: `database1.table` & `database2.table`.

Comment: You're a rockstar! May be that was easy for you... but that was of immense help to me & my team. Thank you very much Sir!